# Carbon-Sulfur Bond Lengths; Resonance Effects (Or Lack Thereof)

Tags: theoretical-chemistry

Why is the C-S bond in $\ce{CH_2SH^-}$ longer than in $\ce{CH_3SH}$? Wouldn't there be resonance in the former, forcing the C-S bond to contract?

http://www.nrcresearchpress.com/doi/pdf/10.1139/v75-431

[image]

[image]

Also while we're at it are there any non *ab initio* calculations/empirical studies on this interesting thiol ion?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is this paper - can you give a DOI link I'm curious what level of theory was done. A naive thought is that there might be some triplet character to the anion.

Comment: Also there will be syn- / anti- (or cis-/trans-) geometry issues with $\ce{CH2SH-}$ that may not have been considered (i.e., I suspect each form will have slightly different bond lengths .. essentially due to differences in the double-bond resonance picture)

Comment: @GeoffHutchison isn't that what you have TAs for? Sorry here's the correct link: http://www.nrcresearchpress.com/doi/pdf/10.1139/v75-431

Comment: I'm most interested in empirical calculations lol. Because if I show my prof this paper I will get an earful about computational chemists, ahem, I mean "chemists." That's just his POV though.

Comment: How would you be able to measure this empirically? That is, how would you be able to make a carbon anion in the presence of a free thiol?

Comment: @jerepierre gas phase? And keep the concentration _very_ low. I don't think the carboanion will form a three-membered ring and eat its tail.

Comment: Starting from what though?

Comment: On a different topic, can you explain what you find interesting about this compound?

Comment: Start from $\ce{H3CSH}$? You're right though I can't see what would selectively remove a methyl proton rather than a thiol proton. So are you saying it's impossible?

Comment: Why is the C-S bond length of the anion longer than the C-S bond length in the neutral thiol? Despite the possibility of resonance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18083/discussion-between-jerepierre-and-dissenter).

Comment: In any case @GeoffHutchison I don't mean to offend you, if that wasn't clear in my previous post about what my prof thinks. That's what he thinks, not me. Personally I'd like to prove my prof wrong about sulfur's bonding tendencies (hence this question ...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Quick Summary

The [linked paper (from 1975)](http://www.nrcresearchpress.com/doi/pdf/10.1139/v75-431) is probably **wrong**. A *slightly* more recent paper ([J. Am. Chem. Soc., 1989, 111 (21), pp 8112–8115](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja00203a007)) suggests the bond lengths are about equal. Some quick calculations (below) using multiple modern methods suggest that, as expected, the C-S bond length in $\ce{CH2SH-}$ is *shorter* than in $\ce{CH3SH}$.

For both older papers, the computational results (using basic Hartree Fock) would be considered highly suspect under modern peer review, since Hartree Fock is known to have problems with anions. Certainly the [1975 paper](http://www.nrcresearchpress.com/doi/pdf/10.1139/v75-431) doesn't even mention the [basis set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_set_(chemistry)).

Seen below, it's clear that the results are method dependent, but the best current methods, with reasonable basis sets indicate the bond length is at least slightly shorter due to some partial double-bond character.

### More Details

The first thing to consider in this is that there are two forms of $\ce{CH2SH-}$, *syn* and *anti*, based on the orientation of the formally C-bound anion and the SH group:

### *syn* form

[image: syn-CH2SH- anion]

### *anti* form

[image: anti-CH2SH- anion]

These will have different bond lengths, since the *anti* form will have contribution of resonance structures **II** and **III** from Ron's answer. This gives some double-bond character and should likely have a shorter bond, although electrostatic repulsion could also be invoked.

The *syn* form won't have a clear effect, since the C anion lone pair and the S lone pairs are on the opposite side of the bond. My guess is that the bond length is about the same as $\ce{CH3SH}$.

I think the clear message is that we can *explain* a lot of things, but it's better to know if our results are accurate before trying to explain them.

What I see with more modern computational methods is that the *syn* form has similar C-S bond length to $\ce{CH3SH}$ and the *anti* form is slightly shorter. I suspect the previous result is simply ***wrong***. Calculations involving anions are tricky, since the extra electron is usually highly diffuse. I expect the basis set was simply insufficient.

The difference in energy between the two forms is ~1 kcal/mol, so experimentally, these will interconvert readily, and an average bond length would be observed. As mentioned in the comments, this species would probably be hard to observe, even in the gas phase, since $\ce{CH3S-}$ is more stable.

### Computed C-S bond lengths (in Å):

For all methods, full geometry optimization was performed using the methods indicated. I would consider the CCSD calculations to be high quality.

[image: bond length table]

Comment: Is it possible to make -H2CSH

Comment: Bleh. I'll make a better table later. Suffice to say that the results are method dependent, and the *syn* form is about the same as CH3SH. I'll give better results later.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison Geoff, in water the 2 lone pairs are hybridized differently, one in a mostly p-orbital, the other in a roughly sp-orbital.  How are you treating the lone pairs in your calculations?

Comment: @ron These are MO calculations with full $C_s$ symmetry for the $\ce{CH2SH-}$ anion, and thus there's no notion of hybridization of lone pairs in these calculations.

Comment: I wonder about the energy difference between syn and anti. It can't be much and most likely might be considered as a free rotation, hence averaging would be appropriate.

Comment: The energy difference seems to be ~1 kcal/mol regardless of method, and so averaging would certainly be appropriate. However, it's interesting that the C-S bond length difference is sometimes fairly significant.

Answer (score 3):

First, the difference we are talking about is only 0.074 A, it's always difficult to be sure what causes such small changes.  That said...

The amount of negative charge on the carbon atom in $\ce{CH3-SH}$ (-0.639) surprises me; it's actually more than in the corresponding anion $\ce{CH2^{-}-SH}$ (-0.620). Note too the significantly greater positive charge on the carbon hydrogens in $\ce{CH3-SH}$.  Perhaps this suggests that hyperconjugated resonance structures like I are important in $\ce{CH3-SH}$.  This would result in the $\ce{C-S}$ bond being shortened to begin with.

[image]

Then, in the case of the anion, resonance structures II and III suggest that there is appreciable negative charge on both carbon and sulfur, consistent with the high $\ce{q_{b}}$ and $\ce{q_{c}}$ values reported in Table I (-0.620, -0.328, respectively).  The appreciable negative charge on both carbon and sulphur, in the anion, results in coulombic repulsion and a slight elongation of the carbon-sulphur bond, from the somewhat shortened bond length observed in the neutral compound.

Comment: Can you think of anyway we can study this thiol ion empirically?

Comment: I would run calculations on the corresponding thioethers and see if the same pattern holds.  If it does, the anion should be accessible from the thioether.

Comment: How would you go from the thioether to the thio-anion? I'd imagine having to cleave the S-R bond ... but then ... we'd have to stick a proton in place of the R to make S-H. How can we selectively put the H on the S rather than on the CH2(-)? @ron

Comment: We're not putting a proton on S.  We'd simply pull a proton off of the methyl in the thioether, that's all, and then we would have a carbanion alpha to sulfur.

Comment: but then we have a inductively donating methyl stuck on the sulfur's other side too. The thing I was thinking about earlier with someone was how do we make -CH2SH so we can study it empirically? Any protecting groups to protect the thiol's proton? And any way to selectively put back the proton on the S?

Comment: @Dissenter  Correct, that's why I said I'd do a calculation first to make sure the shortening effect still occurs in the thioether series.

Comment: can we though make -CH2SH?

Comment: @Dissenter  It's CH3SCH3 that I'm referring to.

Comment: I understand, I'm just curious if synthesis of the anion is possible

Comment: Specifically the H2CSH anion, since you clearly know more about protecting groups. Or are the realities of acid/base chemistry inescapable? I'm thinking that a smart-ass answer would be yes, of course we can make it, just ionize a million moles of CH3SH and hope that probability is in your favor!

Comment: @Dissenter Yes, I suspect it could be generated in the gas phase, but would rearrange very quickly (it is sooo downhill from CH2- to RS-), perhaps too quickly to make whatever measurements are needed.

Comment: Can we zap one molecule in isolation and hope for the best?

Comment: There's a [paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja00203a007) suggesting it might be stable, but I find no manuscripts on this experimentally, except in mass spec fragmentation.

Comment: Dissenter asked, "Can we zap one molecule in isolation and hope for the best?"  That's what the gas-phase experiment is.  But like I said, I would have guessed that intramolecular 1,2 hydrogen shift from S to C would be too fast to allow enough time to record a microwave spectrum (to determine bond lengths) of the initially generated carbon-based anion.  But @GeoffHutchison 's reference suggests an appreciable barrier (46 kcal/m) has been calculated for the hydrogen shift in the  corresponding oxygen case.  I guess that's why we do experiments.

Comment: @ron I'd even guess there's a significant H tunneling rate in the *syn* form (or an inversion from *anti* to *syn* followed by H shift). So I agree it would at least be tough. Unfortunately, my microwave expert retired a few years ago, so I can't ask.